# A Shakesperian inverse alphametic

Tags: knowledge, alphametic, literature

Every digit (in base-10 representation) stands for a letter,
different digits stand for different letters.

```
    233 + 8519 + 954 = 9706
```

The whole is a famous Shakespeare quote.
Which letter does each digit represent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote is

> *Off with his head!*

Digit-to-letter mappings:

> **2** *->* *O*, **3** *->* *f*, **8** *->* *w*, **5** *->* *i*, **1** *->* *t*, **9** *->* *h*, **4** *->* *s*, **7** *->* *e*, **0** *->* *a*, **6** *->* *d*